# How to print a javascript string?

Tags: javascript

I have the following string in a text file (`"` is included). I want to print it in a human-readable way (e.g., removing `"`, and print \uxxxx in readable characters).

I suspect that it is a javascript string. But I am not really sure. Can anybody let me know how to read this file and print the corresponding human-readable string? Thanks.

```
"\u003ctable\u003e\u003ctr\u003e\u003ctd colspan=\u00272\u0027 align=\u0027center\u0027\u003e\u003ctable\u003e\u003ctr\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027left\u0027\u003e\u003cspan style=\"color:#666666;font-size:9pt;font-weight:bold;\"\u003edoi:\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan style=\"color:#666666;font-size:10pt;\"\u003e10.5578/mb.67960\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003c/table\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr\u003e\u003ctd colspan=\u00272\u0027 align=\u0027center\u0027\u003e\u003ctable\u003e\u003ctr\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003c/table\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr\u003e\u003ctd colspan=\u00272\u0027\u003e\u003ctable\u003e\u003ctr\u003e\u003ctd style=\u0027text-align:justify\u0027 class=\u0027icerik5\u0027\u003e\u003chtml\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003chead\u003e\r\n\u003cmeta http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1252\"\u003e\r\n\u003cmeta name=Generator content=\"Microsoft Word 14 (filtered)\"\u003e\r\n\u003cstyle\u003e\r\n\u003c!--\r\n /* Font Definitions */\r\n @font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"MS Mincho\";\r\n\tpanose-1:2 2 6 9 4 2 5 8 3 4;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"MS Mincho\";\r\n\tpanose-1:2 2 6 9 4 2 5 8 3 4;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:Calibri;\r\n\tpanose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:MinionPro-Regular;\r\n\tpanose-1:2 4 5 3 5 3 6 2 2 3;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:StoneSansStd-Medium;\r\n\tpanose-1:0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"\\@MS Mincho\";\r\n\tpanose-1:2 2 6 9 4 2 5 8 3 4;}\r\n /* Style Definitions */\r\n p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal\r\n\t{margin:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\r\n\tfont-size:12.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Cambria\",\"serif\";}\r\np.MsoListParagraph, li.MsoListParagraph, div.MsoListParagraph\r\n\t{margin-top:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-right:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-left:36.0pt;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\r\n\tfont-size:12.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Cambria\",\"serif\";}\r\np.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst\r\n\t{margin-top:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-right:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-left:36.0pt;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\r\n\tfont-size:12.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Cambria\",\"serif\";}\r\np.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle\r\n\t{margin-top:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-right:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-left:36.0pt;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\r\n\tfont-size:12.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Cambria\",\"serif\";}\r\np.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast\r\n\t{margin-top:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-right:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-left:36.0pt;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\r\n\tfont-size:12.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Cambria\",\"serif\";}\r\np.NoParagraphStyle, li.NoParagraphStyle, div.NoParagraphStyle\r\n\t{mso-style-name:\"\\[No Paragraph Style\\]\";\r\n\tmargin:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\r\n\tline-height:120%;\r\n\ttext-autospace:none;\r\n\tfont-size:12.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:MinionPro-Regular;\r\n\tcolor:black;}\r\np.BasicParagraph, li.BasicParagraph, div.BasicParagraph\r\n\t{mso-style-name:\"\\[Basic Paragraph\\]\";\r\n\tmargin:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\r\n\tline-height:120%;\r\n\ttext-autospace:none;\r\n\tfont-size:12.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:MinionPro-Regular;\r\n\tcolor:black;}\r\np.METNNNN, li.METNNNN, div.METNNNN\r\n\t{mso-style-name:MET\\0130NNNN;\r\n\tmargin-top:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-right:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:5.65pt;\r\n\tmargin-left:0cm;\r\n\ttext-align:justify;\r\n\ttext-justify:inter-ideograph;\r\n\ttext-indent:11.35pt;\r\n\tline-height:12.5pt;\r\n\ttext-autospace:none;\r\n\tfont-size:9.5pt;\r\n\tfont-family:StoneSansStd-Medium;\r\n\tcolor:black;}\r\np.ListeParagraf1, li.ListeParagraf1, div.ListeParagraf1\r\n\t{mso-style-name:\"Liste Paragraf1\";\r\n\tmargin-top:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-right:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:8.0pt;\r\n\tmargin-left:0cm;\r\n\tline-height:120%;\r\n\ttext-autospace:none;\r\n\tfont-size:11.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",\"sans-serif\";\r\n\tcolor:black;}\r\nspan.WorddeneAktarlanListeStili1WordRTFeAktarlanListeleriinStiller\r\n\t{mso-style-name:\"Word\\0027den \\0130çe Aktar\\0131lan Liste Stili1 \\(Word\\/RTF \\0130çe Aktar\\0131lan Listeleri \\0130çin Stiller\\)\";}\r\n.MsoChpDefault\r\n\t{font-size:12.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Cambria\",\"serif\";}\r\n@page WordSection1\r\n\t{size:595.3pt 841.9pt;\r\n\tmargin:2.0cm 2.0cm 2.0cm 2.0cm;}\r\ndiv.WordSection1\r\n\t{page:WordSection1;}\r\n /* List Definitions */\r\n ol\r\n\t{margin-bottom:0cm;}\r\nul\r\n\t{margin-bottom:0cm;}\r\n--\u003e\r\np\r\n{font-family:Arial;\r\nfont-size:10pt;\r\nmargin-bottom:0px;\r\nmargin-top:0px;\r\n}\r\n\r\nspan{\r\n\tfont-family:Arial;\r\n\tfont-size:10pt;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0px;\r\n\tmargin-top:0px;\r\n}\r\n.a_link\r\n{\r\n\tcolor:#06C;\r\n\ttext-decoration:underline;\r\n}\r\n.a_link:hover\r\n{\r\n\ttext-decoration:none;\r\n\tcolor:#666;\r\n}\r\n.yazdir:hover\r\n{\r\n\ttext-decoration:none;\r\n}\r\n.master1\r\n{\r\n\tborder-top:1.5px solid #000; \r\n\tborder-bottom:1.5px solid #000; \r\n\theight:32px;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:50px;\r\n}\r\n.master2\r\n{\r\n\twidth:250px; \r\n\theight:25px;\r\n\tbackground-color:#444; \r\n\tpadding:6px 4px 4px 4px;\r\n\tfont-family:Trebuchet MS; \r\n\tcolor:#FFF; \r\n\ttext-align:center; \r\n\tfont-weight:bold; \r\n\tfont-size:16px;\r\n\tmargin-top:-2px;\r\n}\r\n.master3\r\n{\r\n\tfont-family:Trebuchet MS; \r\n\tcolor:#000; \r\n\ttext-align:right; \r\n\tfont-style:italic; \r\n\tmargin-top:-24px; \r\n\tfont-size:14px\r\n}\r\n\r\n.kaynak_li{\r\nfont-family:Arial; \r\nfont-style:normal; \r\nline-height:15pt; \r\nfont-size:10pt; \r\ntext-align:justify; \r\nmargin-bottom:5pt}\r\n\u003c/style\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003c/head\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cbody lang=TR\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv class=\"WordSection1\" style=\"text-align:justify\"\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal align=center style=\u0027margin-bottom:36.0pt;text-align:center;\r\nline-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cb\u003e\u003cspan\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003eInvestigation of Viral Respiratory Tract Infection Agents by \u003cbr\u003eMultiplex PCR Method in Autopsy Cases: A Five-Year Study\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal align=center style=\u0027margin-bottom:36.0pt;text-align:center;\r\nline-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cspan lang=EN-GB\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003eOtopsi Olgular\u0026#305;nda Viral Solunum Yolu Enfeksiyonu Etkenlerinin\u003cbr\u003eMultipleks PCR Yöntemi ile Ara\u0026#351;t\u0026#305;r\u0026#305;lmas\u0026#305;: Be\u0026#351; Y\u0026#305;ll\u0026#305;k Bir Çal\u0026#305;\u0026#351;ma\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027margin-bottom:6.0pt;text-align:justify;text-justify:\r\ninter-ideograph;line-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cb\u003e\u003cspan\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003eNihan Z\u0026#304;YADE\u003csup\u003e1\u003c/sup\u003e, Neval ELGÖRMÜ\u0026#350;\u003csup\u003e1\u003c/sup\u003e, Erdo\u0026#287;an KARA\u003csup\u003e2\u003c/sup\u003e, Ferah KARAYEL\u003csup\u003e3\u003c/sup\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003chr style=\"color:#000; size:0.25px; margin-top:-3pt\" noshade=\"noshade\"\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-ideograph;\r\nline-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cspan\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003e\u003csup\u003e1\u003c/sup\u003e Council of Forensic Medicine, Postmortem Microbiology Laboratory, Istanbul, Turkey.\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-ideograph;\r\nline-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cspan\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003e\u003csup\u003e2\u003c/sup\u003e Council of Forensic Medicine, Autopsy Unit, Istanbul, Turkey.\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-ideograph;\r\nline-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cspan\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003e\u003csup\u003e3\u003c/sup\u003e Council of Forensic Medicine, Histopathology Unit, Istanbul, Turkey.\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027margin-bottom:6.0pt; margin-top:36pt; text-align:justify;text-justify:\r\ninter-ideograph;line-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cb\u003e\u003cspan\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003eABSTRACT\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027margin-bottom:6.0pt;text-align:justify;text-justify:\r\ninter-ideograph;text-indent:14.2pt;line-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;\r\nvertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cspan style=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";\r\ncolor:black\u0027\u003eViral respiratory infections are one of the leading causes of\r\nmorbidity and mortality, especially in children, elderly and immunocompromised\r\npatients. The inclusion of post-mortem studies to diagnose the infection\r\ncausing mortality could be beneficial in specifying new pathogens and\r\ndetermining strategies for treatment and prevention.\u0026nbsp;The aim of this study\r\nwas to research viral etiology by applying multiplex real-time polymerase chain\r\nreaction (Rt-PCR) method in autopsy cases who have been considered to have a\r\nrespiratory infection and to assess whether the viruses detected are the\r\nprimary cause of the infection and whether they have any contributory effect on\r\nthe mortality together with histopathological evidence. In this study, we\r\nincluded a total of 834 cases consisting of sudden death cases from\r\ninfantile-pediatric age group and autopsy cases from \u0026gt; 18 year age group\r\nwith suspected respiratory tract infection in our laboratory between January\r\n2013 and May 2017. Of 834 cases, 468 (56.1%) were male and 366 (43.9%) were\r\nfemale, there were 191 (22.9%) cases between 0-1 months, 593 (71.1%) cases\r\nbetween 1 month-18 years, and 50 (6%) cases in the \u0026gt; 18 years age group. In\r\n728 of 834 (87.3%) cases nasopharyngeal/tracheal swab samples and in 106\r\n(12.7%) of them paraffin-embedded lung tissue samples were studied by the use\r\nof \"FTD Respiratory 21 (Fast-Tract Diagnostics Luxemburg)\" kit, with multiplex\r\nRt-PCR method. The post-mortem samples were evaluated for human rhinovirus\r\n(HRV), parainfluenza viruses (PIV) (1, 2, 3, 4), influenza virus type A and B\r\n(INF-A, INF-B), enterovirus (EV), human bocavirus (HBoV), adenovirus (AdV),\r\nhuman coronavirus (HCoV 229,63,HKU,43), human metapneumovirus A ve B\r\n(HMPV-A/B), parechovirus, respiratory syncytial virus (RSV A/B) and \u003ci\u003eMycoplasma\r\npneumoniae\u003c/i\u003e. In our study, at least one respiratory virus was detected by\r\nRt-PCR in 379 (45.4%) of total 834 cases, whereas no viral agent was identified\r\nin 455 (54.6%) of the cases. One viral agent was detected in 278 (33.3%), two\r\nviral agents were detected in 83 (9.94%) and three viral agents were detected\r\nin 18 (2.16%) cases. Overall, the most common viral agent was HRV 110 (13.2%)\r\nfollowed by AdV 39 (4.7%) and RSV A/B 33 (4%). In pediatric cases the rate of\r\npositive results for respiratory viruses was 31.8% and in adult group it was\r\n20% (p= 0.032). The most common virus detected among children was HRV and INF-A\r\nin adult group. In 101 (12.1%) cases infections caused by two or three agents\r\nwere diagnosed. Infections with two causative agents were detected as 2.6%\r\n(5/191) in 0-1 month age group, 13% (77/593) in 1 month-18 year age group and\r\n2% (1/50) in \u0026gt; 18 age group. The most frequently observed co-infections with\r\ndouble causative agents were HRV and INF-B, HRV and PIV, HRV and HBoV, HRV and\r\nAdV combinations. Infections with three causative agents were detected\r\ncompletely among 1 month-18 year age [3% (18/593)] group. In our study, 318\r\n(38.1%) cases had no signs of infection in the postmortem histopathological\r\nexamination of the lung tissues, while the most common finding was lobular\r\npneumonia/purulent bronchitis in 233 (28%) cases and the second was\r\ninterstitial pneumonia in 168 (20.1%) cases. When all cases were evaluated in\r\nterms of infection, positive results were detected in 469 (56.2%) cases. As a result;\r\npostmortem microbiological diagnosis with autopsy and histopathological\r\ndetection of the patients who are thought to have respiratory tract infection\r\nwill also determine the infectious agents causing death.\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027margin-bottom:6.0pt;text-align:justify;text-justify:\r\ninter-ideograph;text-indent:14.2pt;line-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;\r\nvertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cb\u003e\u003ci\u003e\u003cspan style=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";\r\ncolor:black\u0027\u003eKeywords:\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/b\u003e\u003cspan style=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\r\n\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003e \u003ci\u003eRespiratory tract infections; multiplex\r\nPCR; respiratory viruses; post-mortem diagnosis.\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027margin-bottom:6.0pt;text-align:justify;text-justify:\r\ninter-ideograph;text-indent:14.2pt;line-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;\r\nvertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cb\u003e\u003cspan style=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";\r\ncolor:black\u0027\u003eReceived:\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/b\u003e\u003cspan style=\u0027font-size:\r\n10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003e 16.11.2018 - \u003cb\u003eAccepted:\u003c/b\u003e 06.02.2019\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027margin-top:30.0pt;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom:\r\n6.0pt;margin-left:0cm;text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-ideograph;\r\nline-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cb\u003e\u003cspan\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003eCorrespondence:\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027margin-bottom:2.0pt;text-align:justify;text-justify:\r\ninter-ideograph;line-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cb\u003e\u003cspan\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003eUzm. Dr.\r\nNihan Ziyade,\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027margin-bottom:2.0pt;text-align:justify;text-justify:\r\ninter-ideograph;line-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cspan\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003e\u0026#304;stanbul\r\nAdli T\u0026#305;p Kurumu Ba\u0026#351;kanl\u0026#305;\u0026#287;\u0026#305;,\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027margin-bottom:2.0pt;text-align:justify;text-justify:\r\ninter-ideograph;line-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cspan\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003ePostmortem\r\nMikrobiyoloji Laboratuvar\u0026#305;, \u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027margin-bottom:2.0pt;text-align:justify;text-justify:\r\ninter-ideograph;line-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cspan\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003eBahçelievler,\r\n\u0026#304;stanbul, Türkiye. \u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027margin-bottom:2.0pt;text-align:justify;text-justify:\r\ninter-ideograph;line-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cb\u003e\u003cspan\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003ePhone:\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/b\u003e\u003cspan style=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";\r\ncolor:black\u0027\u003e +90 212 454 15 00, \u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cp class=MsoNormal style=\u0027margin-bottom:6.0pt;text-align:justify;text-justify:\r\ninter-ideograph;line-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\u0027\u003e\u003cb\u003e\u003cspan\r\nstyle=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";color:black\u0027\u003eE-mail:\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/b\u003e\u003cspan style=\u0027font-size:10.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\",\"sans-serif\";\r\ncolor:black\u0027\u003e \u003ca href=\"mailto:nihanziyade@gmail.com\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"a_link\"\u003enihanziyade@gmail.com\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003c/body\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003c/html\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003c/table\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr\u003e\u003ctd colspan=\u00272\u0027 align=\u0027center\u0027\u003e\u003ctable\u003e\u003ctr\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027left\u0027\u003e[ \u003ca class=\u0027spm3\u0027 href=\u0027fulltext?212?21665\u0027\u003eFulltext\u003c/a\u003e ]\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027left\u0027\u003e[ \u003ca target=\u0027blank\u0027 class=\u0027spm3\u0027 href=\u0027/managete/fu_folder/2019-02/2019-53-2-179-191.pdf\u0027\u003ePDF\u003c/a\u003e ]\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003c/table\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003c/table\u003e"
```

Comment: Have you tried just `print()`ing it? Those are Unicode escape sequences that correspond to regular Unicode characters. Python should figure it out, assuming you're using Python 3.

Comment: It looks like it might be html code. Use the browser to render it, or there are various encode/decode utilities out there on the web

Comment: this is css--use a text editor with regular expression support and replace \t with two spaces and \r\n with a newline.

Comment: I mean, the vast majority of it is css--the shell is html

Answer (score 0):

um, I think its pretty much valid HTML. So, just put it in a file and use a browser?

otherwise, its indeed a valid JS string. So, just assing it to a variable (`const myStr = "\u003ctab...` and then do with it whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. I got this by using console.log() around the string

```
<table><tr><td colspan='2' align='center'><table><tr><td align='left'><span style="color:#666666;font-size:9pt;font-weight:bold;">doi:</span><span style="color:#666666;font-size:10pt;">10.5578/mb.67960</span></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' align='center'><table><tr></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'><table><tr><td style='text-align:justify' class='icerik5'><html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered)">
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:"MS Mincho";
    panose-1:2 2 6 9 4 2 5 8 3 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"MS Mincho";
    panose-1:2 2 6 9 4 2 5 8 3 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:MinionPro-Regular;
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 3 6 2 2 3;}
@font-face
    {font-family:StoneSansStd-Medium;
    panose-1:0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"\@MS Mincho";
    panose-1:2 2 6 9 4 2 5 8 3 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoListParagraph, li.MsoListParagraph, div.MsoListParagraph
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.NoParagraphStyle, li.NoParagraphStyle, div.NoParagraphStyle
    {mso-style-name:"\[No Paragraph Style\]";
    margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    line-height:120%;
    text-autospace:none;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:MinionPro-Regular;
    color:black;}
p.BasicParagraph, li.BasicParagraph, div.BasicParagraph
    {mso-style-name:"\[Basic Paragraph\]";
    margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    line-height:120%;
    text-autospace:none;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:MinionPro-Regular;
    color:black;}
p.METNNNN, li.METNNNN, div.METNNNN
    {mso-style-name:MET\0130NNNN;
    margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:5.65pt;
    margin-left:0cm;
    text-align:justify;
    text-justify:inter-ideograph;
    text-indent:11.35pt;
    line-height:12.5pt;
    text-autospace:none;
    font-size:9.5pt;
    font-family:StoneSansStd-Medium;
    color:black;}
p.ListeParagraf1, li.ListeParagraf1, div.ListeParagraf1
    {mso-style-name:"Liste Paragraf1";
    margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:8.0pt;
    margin-left:0cm;
    line-height:120%;
    text-autospace:none;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:black;}
span.WorddeneAktarlanListeStili1WordRTFeAktarlanListeleriinStiller
    {mso-style-name:"Word\0027den \0130çe Aktar\0131lan Liste Stili1 \(Word\/RTF \0130çe Aktar\0131lan Listeleri \0130çin Stiller\)";}
.MsoChpDefault
    {font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
@page WordSection1
    {size:595.3pt 841.9pt;
    margin:2.0cm 2.0cm 2.0cm 2.0cm;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
 /* List Definitions */
 ol
    {margin-bottom:0cm;}
ul
    {margin-bottom:0cm;}
-->
p
{font-family:Arial;
font-size:10pt;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-top:0px;
}

span{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:10pt;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
.a_link
{
    color:#06C;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.a_link:hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#666;
}
.yazdir:hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.master1
{
    border-top:1.5px solid #000; 
    border-bottom:1.5px solid #000; 
    height:32px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
.master2
{
    width:250px; 
    height:25px;
    background-color:#444; 
    padding:6px 4px 4px 4px;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS; 
    color:#FFF; 
    text-align:center; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    font-size:16px;
    margin-top:-2px;
}
.master3
{
    font-family:Trebuchet MS; 
    color:#000; 
    text-align:right; 
    font-style:italic; 
    margin-top:-24px; 
    font-size:14px
}

.kaynak_li{
font-family:Arial; 
font-style:normal; 
line-height:15pt; 
font-size:10pt; 
text-align:justify; 
margin-bottom:5pt}
</style>

</head>

<body lang=TR>

<div class="WordSection1" style="text-align:justify">

<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:36.0pt;text-align:center;
line-height:15.0pt;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle'><b><span
style='fo
undefined
﻿
​
```